# Need to locate documentation of FCPX XML ver 1.9

Tags: fcpx, xml

I have found a [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/EventsandProjects/EventsandProjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011227-CH12-SW14) of version 1.8 of the FCPX XML. It is not globally searchable - only section by section and is not for the latest version.

I have an XML file recently emitted from FCPX and it has a version tag "<fcpxml version="1.9">".

Comment: Apple seems to have messed up their documentation. The current documenation website eventually leads to a link to the unmaintained documentation archive. You should contact Apple and ask them to publish the documentation for version 1.9. That's also the place to complain about the search function. Without complaints they have no incentive to fix it. In the meantime use Google's site: -keyword along with the relevant part of the URL and your search terms to search the documenation globally. See here: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en under "Search for a specific site".

Answer (score 1):

Apple didn't update all the documentation. Found it only here: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/document_type_definition?changes=la__1)

Comment: Strictly speaking a DTD is not a documentation. It's helpful to validate the correct syntax of an xml file but doesn't explain anything.

Comment: At least, we can check what's new in FCPXML 1.9. Didn't found anything except new media-rep element.